# Unbind jQuery click event from the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All the elements with `.btn` class are bound to a `jQuery` click event on page load. Is there a way to unbind a single element that uses the class `.btn`. I tried by adding `return false` in the `onclick` event to an anchor tag like this

`<a href="index.html" class="btn" onclick="return false;" target="_blank">Link</a>`

but it doesn't seem to override or prevent it from performing the click event bound by `jQuery`

**EDIT**
Thanks for all the answers, but is there an inline solution to this? Something like `onclick="event.preventDefault();"`

Also follow up question: Just curious, which among `onclick` and `jQuery` event listener gets called first?

Comment: while you can change onclick event  why you not just delete the href  or  change to href="#"

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I need that link in hence the `index.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you added event click via delegation** like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(e){});
```

You must stop event propagation from your own .btn

```
$('.myOwnBtn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

How do you add event click on your `.btn` ? 
If you add event by click, you can off it

```
$('.myOwnBtn').off('click');
```

`Onclick` attribute is executed before click event from jquery and is completely independent from click event from jquery.

Comment: Thanks! So does that mean whatever you put in `onclick` gets overridden by `jQuery`? Also which does get called first? `onclick` or the `jQuery` click event?

Comment: Attribute onclick is executed first but it is independent from event handler system.

Answer (score 3):

Use `unbind()` method of Jquery.

```
<a href="index.html" onclick="return false;" target="_blank" id="xyz">Link</a>      

$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#xyz").unbind("click");
});
```

Comment: a little explanation wouldnt hurt

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `.not` to narrow the selection with a specific button where you need to give this button a unique id:

```
<a href="index.html" class="btn" id="prevent" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a href="index.html" class="btn"  target="_blank">Link</a>

$(".btn").not("#prevent").click(function(){

});
```

Comment: I already did this but I'm looking for an inline solution. This was my last resort. Thanks!